# Custom user model not working in foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-custom-user

I have created a custom user model which is working fine. 
The problem is when access the user from foreign key, it throws me :

> DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(51) is not present in table "auth_user".

My custom user is **userauth**,  clearly the model still looking for the original User model instead of the custom one.

Here is what I did:

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userauth.UserAuth'

#models.py
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,blank=True,default=None)

#admin.py
class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this instead (don't bother assigning variables):

**models.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    # You don't need 'default=None'
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The 'default=None' caused the problem. Wonder why it will affect the custom user model though.

Comment: @dev-jim When you set `default=None`, you are overriding the ForeignKey and saying, "Make the field equal to nothing." Then trying to call that field, you are trying to call nothing. In essence, you're having a conversation with no body when you try to call it from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!